# Support Jersey in OpenAPI 3

Tags: java, spring, jersey, openapi, springdoc

We are adding (swagger) OpenAPI 3 to our Spring application,

We have also Jersey endpoints (using `@Path`), and from [docs](https://springdoc.org/) it isn't supported

> Does springdoc-openapi support Jersey?

> If you are using JAX-RS and as implementation Jersey (@Path for example), we do not support it.

What can we do to expose jersey endpoints? must we move to Spring's `@RestController`, or is there jersey support or workaround?

Found a close [issue](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/183)

> We only support exposing Rest Endpoints using spring managed beans (`@RestController` for example).
> You can have a look at swagger-jaxrs2 if it can help:

> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/2.0/java/java-jersey2-minimal

Comment: [Swagger-Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) has support for Jersey. And I'm not aware of a workaround that's popular. It'll be a better idea to either move to one framework, or in the worst case, try separating the projects into two different apps.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Swagger-Core is part of Open API 3 bundle

Comment: @PaulSamsotha is there any support?

Comment: If you're mixing Jersey and Spring annotations, I guess there'll be no support. But if your APIs are based on one single framework, you can better align the swagger integration to one particular framework. From my personal experience, I've worked on APIs built on Jersey but integrated using Spring Beans, and there we just stick to Swagger-Core integration and not rely on Springdoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was to migrate Jersey endpoints to `@RestController`.

For example changing:

`@ApplicationPath` -> `@RequestMapping`

`@QueryParam` -> `@RequestParam`

`@Path` + `@POST` -> `@PostMapping`